# Ubuntu 16.04 Installation stuck

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, laptop

I've been trying to install Ubuntu on my new Acer Spin 1 for a few days now and whenever it reaches a point it gets stuck and loops the same code over and over indefinitely. This lasts for hours:

```
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:xxx: Warning: Source ID xxxxx was not found when attempting to remove it.
GLib. source_remove(self.timeout_id)

/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:xxx: Warning: Source ID xxxxx was not found when attempting to remove it
GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
```

(The x's are a string of numbers that increase through each loop).

The stages it stalls on varies from 'installing grub package' to the more common 'Configuring linux-signed-image-generic (amd64)'.

I did end up getting it installed by setting up the partitions myself but that only led me to another issue where I'd receive the error 'No Boot Drive' on restart: [No Bootable Device after Installing Ubuntu 16.04 - No Drives in UEFI BIOS settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019028/no-bootable-device-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-no-drives-in-uefi-bios-settin) ... I ended up attempting a reinstall to find a solution and now I'm back to where I started. They method I tried that was successful before no longer seems to work.

Please help.

Comment: What are your computer specs?

Comment: It's got an Intel Pentium Quad Core 1.10 GHz Processor, Intel HD Graphics, 4GB RAM, and 64GB HDD. I should mention that everything works great up until this point in installation; trying without installing shows no problems.

Comment: How strange. It should install it correctly. Try debugging it, maybe edit the question to clarify more, if you please.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that the way to install it 'properly' is to create the bootable USB as a GPT partition scheme (I originally had it set to MBR for UEFI and BIOS); install without internet, updates, or Third-Party Software, and manually create the partitions according to this guide: http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/10/30/gpt-and-mbr-manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-15-10/... Now that it's finally installed, I just need to deal with this issue: [No Bootable Device after Installing Ubuntu 16.04 - No Drives in UEFI BIOS settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019028/no-bootable-device-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-no-drives-in-uefi-bios-settin?noredirect=1#comment1654380_1019028)

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting for 4 hours against this in a Lenovo-Something. What worked for me was:

1. Go into the Live CD
2. Open GParted and delete all partitions. My computer also complained here because the Live CD was mounting the Hard Drive of the laptop (which is the hard drive that I was trying to format with GParted) in the directory /cdrom. While it is mounted GParted wont be able to erase it, and if you try to unmount it, the laptop will complain saying that it is being used. You need to run `fuser -cuk /mnt` to kill all processes using `/cdrom`. Then you can unmount `/cdrom` and use GParted to eliminate all partitions.
3. Go into the Live CD again and install Ubuntu as usual

These steps worked for me.

Comment: You can format the partition in the installation step as far as I remember...no need for this.